# Multi-Scale/Resolution C++ Container

Tags: c++, templates, containers, signal-processing, mipmaps

I'm looking for a C++ array/vector-like container (template is a plus) that automatically builds an internal multi-resolution representation (mipmap) of the data preferrably using downsampling by 2 (dyadic) by default. My primary plan is to use it in processing sampled waves, that is audio and radio signals but a general template for 1, 2, or 3 dimensions would be an extra bonus. Backends for OpenGL or OpenCL would be super-cool.

/Per

Comment: sounds pretty cool, when you've done one, you could submit it to boost.

Comment: Ok. How do I submit to Boost?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/development/submissions.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to build this from legos. I know of no container to do what you want.